# Changing a picture by clicking on it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, switch-statement

This is my first ever question on here and I figure it must have a simple answer but it's frustrated me for a while, especially since I'm new to Javascript. So I have many images and would like to change to the next one by clicking on it on the webpage, starting with a certain image, obviously. Now I could do this with nested if else statements but if you have many images you get too many ones nested into each other and it can get too complex so I figured there must be a simpler way of doing it. Here's an example of the code I had:

```
function changeImage() 
{
var image=document.getElementById("mainImage")

if (image.src.match("image1.jpg"))
{
  image.src="image2.jpg";
}
else if (image.src.match("image2.jpg"))
{
  image.src="image3.jpg";
}
else
{
  if (image.src.match("image3.jpg"))
  {
    image.src="image4.jpg";
  }
  else
  {
    image.src="image1.jpg";
  }
}
}
```

So you can see it's not the best way to do it. I tried to do it with a switch statement but I couldn't either (and would appreciate it if someone told me if it could be done with one and how). As a last try I tried this but for some reason it jumps from image1 to image4 at once:

```
function changeImage()
{
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"]
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage")

for (i=0; i < images.length; i++)
{
  if (myImage.src.match(images[i]))
  {
    myImage.src = images[i+1]
  }
}
}
```

So I could really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last changeImage goes to #4 immediately because you're changing the image in the for loop which causes the check within the loop to keep being true and so it runs all the way to the last index, at which point the check finally fails.  Instead, you'll want to maintain the current image index with a variable.  Then, just change myImage.src to images[currentIndex + 1] on each click.  Try something like below.  You'll want to run showNextImage on page load and then run it once each time the image is clicked.

```
<script>
var currentImageIndex = 0;

//Cycle through images
showNextImage() {
   var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"]
   var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage")

   myImage.src = images[currentImageIndex];

   currentImageIndex++;
   if(currentImageIndex >= images.length)
      currentImageIndex = 0;
}
</script>
```